# Not getting any/correct Visual Studio suggestions in .Net Core

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio C# .Net 6.0, when I want to instantiate the type `SqlConnection`.

For example, I expect VS to give me suggestions to load the correct library via `Nuget`;

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient,
```

but it doesn't.

This is an issue even though I already loaded the same library in the same solution.

Comment: Please provide example. I'm not sure that VS will suggest something used in different project.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević The example is in the question - Type SqlConnection > right-click > Quick Actions and Refactorings. This should give a suggestion to reference the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient library. It isn't doing this even when that library is loaded in my solution. (I would expect it to suggest downloading it from Nuget, even if it wasn't included in my solution.)

Comment: Shortcut to tell VS or VS Code that you want suggestions is `Ctrl` + `.` . For some reason it suggests `System.Security.Permissions` package. I'm not sure that suggestions are configurable. If they are I would want to know more about it.

Comment: If this was my question, I would provide screenshots to prove that package is installed, and to show that I'm using it in same project. I was able to reproduce this in my project, but someone else maybe wouldn't. With screenshots you are sure that other users would understand issue.